# How to extract multiple patterns in a string using regex in Java

Tags: regex

I have a String that looks like this

<34>Any Character ]
<23>Any Character ]

I want to extract the string based on the starting and the end line. I am trying to create two strings with

String str1 should have <34>Any Character ]
and String str2 should have <23>Any Character ]

Here is my regex = "^<[0-9]*>[0-9]+.*\n" Its only giving me  <34>Any Character ]
I also need to get the second line too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
(<[\d]{2}>[\w\s]*])
```

Java escaped version -

```
(<[\\d]{2}>[\\w\\s]*])
```

should give you two groups as required.